# Routing table for 2 interfaces

Tags: ssh, iptables, routing, route, interface

I have the following interfaces

```
eth0 192.168.1.178 subnet mask 255.255.255.0 default gateway 192.168.1.1
eth1 10.4.0.6      subnet mask 255.255.255.252 default gateway 10.4.0.5
```

I want eth1 only can communicate with 10.4.0.5/30 network, rest of the traffic should go through 192.168.1.1 .
In this setup I can't ssh to 10.64.0.0/30 network.

How can I configure my routing table for this setup?

**These are my current settings:**

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) 
Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.178/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 547025sec preferred_lft 547025sec
    inet6 fe80::d50:e658:eec:9444/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

7: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1436 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether YY:YY:YY:YY:YY:YY brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.64.0.6/30 brd 10.64.0.7 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft 5835sec preferred_lft 5835sec
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0

0.0.0.0         10.64.0.5       0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1

0.0.0.0         10.64.0.5       0.0.0.0         UG    102    0        0 eth1

10.64.0.4       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     101    0        0 eth1

192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Comment: What did you already try? 0.0.0.0 equals any, so you don't want that on all of your interfaces. Remove the route/gateway and add one for your desired network.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean I should only keep this line ?
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0

Comment: If you drive your car and see multiple singns pointing to different directions, maybe with different distances, you would choose the shortest. If this road is closed you would drive one of the others. Do they bring you to this target? Then you have your answer.